# AndEngine - Changing scene not working

Tags: android, andengine, scene

In the `onAreaTouch()` method I have some modifiers. In the delay modifier there is a `onModifierFinished()` method and there I want to change the scene like:

```
Scene scene = new Scene();    
Game_Screen.this.getEngine().setScene(scene);
```

But nothing happens. I am sure it comes to this line, but scene does not change.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Make sure you are getting the correct instance of Engine.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are doing these changes on the AndEngine update thread:

```
runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scene scene = new Scene();
        Game_Screen.this.getEngine().setScene(scene);
    }
});
```